# LAN inter-process communication in C#?

Tags: c#, wcf, concurrency, communication

What's the easiest way to implement lan interprocess communication?
I need process on machine A be blocked until process on machine B send him just a simple string msg

Don't know if it is worth building a whole WCF project.

What Do you say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Go WCF.**

Why creating something on your own, when there is this perfectly suited library? WCF can exactly what you need out of the box. It supports those synchronous blocking calls you need.

Do yourself a favor and learn it, you will not regret.

Answer (score 0):

I had thought there was a win32 "named" object that could be created, potentially able to serve this capability.  I'm not spotting it on net searches though.  Of course you could try to use the BCL socket mechanisms directly, blocking for a socket accept.  You could also try .net remoting, though I'm not sure it would be more light-weight than WCF.

Ultimately WCF might be best.  If you use self-hosting, then I don't think it is as heavy-weight as you are thinking.